# How to set a countdown timer with a start time and an end time from the DB? C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Inside my DB I have stored a DateTime value for "StartDate" and "EndDate", and was wondering how I would create a countdown timer using these two values?

I have managed to use a timer to create a countdown with one value but not two.
Is there a way to do this? I am currently working with ASP.NET, C# and SQL.

Comment: Can you use Javascript/jQuery? There are plenty of countdown code plugins out there...

Comment: Yes I can but I would like to stay in c# if possible. All I need to do is figure out how to set a start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Ticks. Place some string into your database and save the ticks value.
It's almost like guid's.. It will never repeat.
Something like that:

```
private string ReturnUniqueTick()
{
    return DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
}
```

And then you create an index for this field in your database, what will ensure you will have an unique number or formatted string..

Hope this help.